# How to plot with x in decreasing order?

Tags: python, plot, sympy

Sometimes y increases when x decreases:

[image]

```
from sympy import symbols, plot

p = symbols('p', positive=True)
h = (3.731444 - p**0.1902631) / 0.841728e-4

p_low = 150
p_high = 1013.25

plot(h, (p, p_low, p_high), axis_center=(p_low,0))
```

It can be more convenient to have a curve growing towards the top-right corner, it is possible to do that with sympy `plot` function?

I tried using reversed `range` and reversed `extent` without success.

Comment: a dirty easy fix will be just to pass `xlim=(max, min)` to `plot`

Comment: @cards: That works and is an acceptable solution for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be achieved by swapping the order of the `xlim`:

`plot(h, (p, p_low, p_high), axis_center=(p_low,0), xlim=(max, min))`

---

Using the `plot`'s `backend` parameter you can access also to the *matplolib* backend. It has the advantage that you can inject your `matplotlib` commands. A subclass of `BaseBackend` is required.
See [source code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/26f7bdbe3f860e7b4492e102edec2d6b429b5aaf/sympy/plotting/plot.py#L1282-L1564) of [MatplotlibBackend](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html?highlight=plot#sympy.plotting.plot.MatplotlibBackend) for details.

Here an illustrative example:

```
import sympy.plotting.plot as plot
from sympy.plotting.plot import MatplotlibBackend
from sympy import symbols


class SwapXAxis(MatplotlibBackend):

    def show(self):
        # here matplolib code

        for ax in self.ax:
            # reverse scale on x-axis
            ax.invert_xaxis()
            # anchor the y-axis at the new origin
            ax.spines['right'].set_position('zero')
            # adjust labels and ticks
            ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position("right")
            ax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")

        # call parent method
        super().show()


p = symbols('p', positive=True)
h = (3.731444 - p**0.1902631) / 0.841728e-4

p_low = 150
p_high = 1013.25


plot(h, (p, p_low, p_high), backend=SwapXAxis, axis_center=(p_low,0))
```

Comment: @cards [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77522301/how-to-change-sympy-plot-properties-in-jupyter-with-matplotlib-methods/77524468?noredirect=1#77524468) another example of a custom `Backend`